# US vs EU weather systems commercialization and precision?

Tags: meteorology, numerical-modelling, satellites

The US and EU have very different government funding systems for weather and space equipment, perhaps as different as the road systems. The US has a higher performing health system on average at a higher price, what about the weather, how does the EU and US compare in that field? What areas of weather prediction and measurement do both regions perform best, and what is different about the commercialization?

Comment: https://www.globalweatherclimatecenter.com/weather-education/european-vs-american-weather-models-whats-the-difference

Comment: With regard to "*The US has a higher performing health system on average at a higher price*". The "higher price" is not debatable. However, the "higher performing health system" is highly debatable. This dubious claim is orthogonal to the question at hand. You might want to delete that part of the question.

Comment: @trondhansen The embarrassing performance of government-funded US models regarding Sandy was one of many motivating principles behind a significant update of those government-funded US forecasting models. Commercial models are of course worse.

Comment: Regarding Europe: https://rmets.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/met.1470

Comment: Regarding the US: https://www.forbes.com/sites/jimfoerster/2020/01/24/whats-the-difference-between-private-weather-companies-and-the-national-weather-service/?sh=39662bea4a29